# Error while trying to install Babel JSX precompiler

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

Hi am getting the following error while trying to precompile my JSX code. I have been using it but something happened and I am unable to install this

> npm install babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react

It is showing this error message:

> npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs"
>   "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "babel-preset-es2015" "babel-preset-react"
>   npm ERR! node v4.4.5 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5 npm ERR! file
>   /home/name/.npm/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/6.8.0/package/package.json
>   npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
>
> npm ERR! Failed to parse json npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at
>   1:1374 npm ERR!
>   e#readme","_id":"is-finite@1.0.1","_from":"is-finite@>=1.0.0 <2.0.0"}
>   npm ERR!
>   ^ npm ERR! File:
>   /home/name/.npm/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/6.8.0/package/package.json
>   npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data. npm ERR! package.json must
>   be actual JSON, not just JavaScript. npm ERR!  npm ERR! This is not a
>   bug in npm. npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json
>   file. JSON.parse
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /var/www/html/js/npm-debug.log

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to install those seperatly.?

Comment: i guess your `package.json` is in wrong format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install globally on your computer those modules, add `-g`:

```
npm install -g babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react
```

Otherwise, it meand you want to install it locally. Make sure your have `package.json` in the root used to launch that command. Follow [package rules](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). [Here](http://browsenpm.org/package.json) is an example. Your can try to validate your `package.json` on [package-json-validator.com](http://package-json-validator.com/)